# display GeoReferencing image through MapServer

Tags: c#, google-maps, geolocation, tiff, mapserver

I have a tiff image and got the world file which contains the needed information for GeoReferenceing,

how to start add this image on Mapserver ? if I use C# and use GMAP API to call the google server through internet to show map.

how to add this map with correct coordinate on it ? if I have to replace this API to have a local map server to use, it is ok as long as I still can use the new mapserver and API with C# windows application.

any suggestion? I have many times add similar to this question but all people answer to use GDAL, but I think GDAL to get the needed information which is already having them in the world file ?

Answer (score 0):

GDAL is the core lib of MapServer. The way of publish a georeferenced raster image is mapserver can be found here : http://mapserver.org/input/raster.html

Very straightforward, but you may still want to be careful about:

First, you may want to run gdalinfo to get the coordination system info for your image to make sure what is the coordinate system and find out the EPSG number to see if it is supported in the proj4 in your mapserver.

Second,remember to make sure in the mapfile the 'data' is using a relative path. Make sure your tiff is put into the correct path you assigned to.

Third to test the wms, you may need a valid bbox for the area in the same unit and coordinate system to put into the wms request url.